# Replace values in one DEM with values from another DEM

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, mosaic

I have two DEMS. One is a 10m DEM (let's call it DEM-A) covering a large area (projection EPSG 4326). The other is a higher resolution DEM (DEM-B) that was constructed from a structure-from-motion point cloud, but has since been down-sampled to 10m and projected into the same coordinate system (EPSG 4326).
I need to replace the values in DEM-A with the values in DEM-B where there are such, and keep all values of DEM-A where there there is nothing (i.e. nodata in DEM-B or no coverage of DEM-B).

In the image below, you can see parts of DEM-A on the right, and parts of DEM-B on the left. Black cells are nodata (-9999). You can see that the grids don't quite match, so DEM-B will need to be resampled to fit the grid in DEM-A.

I feel like this should be a straigthforward conditional statement, but I can't get it to work. Happy to get suggestions for QGIS, gdal, or anything open source.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged gdal in your question. This seems like the perfect job for something like [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html).

Comment: I tried merge in QGIS which crashes with a mysterious error about format [*Format driver GMT does not support creation and piecewise writing.
Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine)*], and I've tried to run *gdalwarp demA demB mosaic*, which replaces the corresponding values of demB in demA, but unfortunately keeps the nodata values (-9999) in the output file (i.e. around the are covered by demA).

Comment: Have you tried the nodata options of [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html), `-n` and `-a_nodata`?